# XPath. Check if image is in "Test2" row.

Tags: xpath

I would like to check if the image is in the "Test2" row (and not in the second row). So how can I do this?

Tell me if i'm not clear enough.

I've got this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <img src=/QCAdmin/Content/Images/Check.gif alt="logoIsDefault"/>
        </td>
        <td>blabla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"></td>
        <td>blabla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When, I click on some link, the image change rows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"></td>
        <td>blabla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td>blabla</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <img src=/QCAdmin/Content/Images/Check.gif alt="logoIsDefault"/>
        </td>
        <td>blabla</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want an xpath which returns reference to `<img>` if it is in correct position, and nothing if there is no `<img>` at all or if `<img>` is positioned incorrectly? What should happen if there is an `<img>` in both correct and incorrect position? And when there are many images in the table? What is an expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this returns anything:

```
//table/tr[td='Test2']/td/img
```

can be done like:

```
boolean(//table/tr[td='Test2']/td/img)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you pour replying. Infortunatlly, it doesn't work. of course if i try this : `//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/img` it's works great but as you well understood it's not what i want :)

Comment: I fixed the problem ! `//table/tbody/tr['Test2']/td/img` works great ! Thanks you for putting me on the track :)

Comment: I found an other way : `//table/tbody/tr/td[text()='Test2']/../td/img` and it works better than the previous solution

Comment: Nice, in what manner does it work better ? BTW, you can try //table/tbody/tr[td/text()='Test2']/td/img and avoid going FW & BW in the DOM tree